# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'motempl'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I have AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'motempl' with python 3.6.9 and opencv-contrib-python==4.0.0.21, opencv-python==4.0.0.21.

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.motempl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'motempl'
>>>
```

Please help to solve the issue

Comment: Show the stack trace

Comment: @DaveW.Smith i have updated the log, could you please check it